# Google Sheets: how to use Conditional formatting to make cells with formulas bold, and cells with user-typed data normal

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like a conditional formatting rule to mark cells with formulas one way, and cells with user-typed values instead of formulas another way. This way you can quickly see which cells are filled by formulas and which are not.

For example (this is a trivial, made-up example to make my point): a cell contains a `1` in it. I want it bold if that `1` comes from some formula, like `=if(A1=today(), 1, 0)`, and I want it *not* bold if the user actually just typed a `1` into the cell. Make sense?

Again, I'm looking for a general-purpose way to identify formula-filled vs user-typed cells.

I am unable to figure it out. Choosing the "Custom formula is" allows you to enter a custom formula to run, rather than matching if a custom formula exists in that cell.

See also: Google's help: [Use conditional formatting rules in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have FORMULATEXT, that returns the formula as a string and an error if there's no formula:

```
=IFNA(FORMULATEXT(A1),"It's not a formula!")="It's not a formula!"
```

---

I suggest reading all "Blind Spots" comments! Then, I'm leaving here that I just found that there is a function called ISFORMULA, that will return true if it's a formula:

```
=ISFORMULA(A1)
```

Or, for user input:

```
=ISFORMULA(A1)<>TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for all your input! It's truly worthy!

Comment: `isformula()` is just what I needed! Upvoted. Thank you. I have extended your answer with a screenshot and additional instructions [in my answer here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/171201/126659).

Answer (score -1):

##### How to apply conditional formatting in Google Sheets to only cells which contain a formula:

[As @Martin says](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/171173/126659), [`=isformula()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6270316) works! I upvoted that answer, but want to extend it by:

1. showing a screenshot, and
2. fully answering the question, which is: "how to use Conditional formatting to make cells with formulas bold, and cells with user-typed data normal"

Here, I selected the entire D column by clicking the column heading, then I went to Format --> Conditional formatting. I chose `Custom formula is`, and `=isformula(D1)` to apply my custom formatting to all cells in Column D which contain a formula. For the custom formatting, I chose no fill, and bold. **Now, all cells in Column D which contain a formula are automatically made bold! But if I manually type in a value, they are not bold. Perfect!**

[image]

Comment: @BlindSpots, I did upvote the other answer. I also marked it as correct to give the person credit for their work. My answer is not a "thank you comment". It's a stand-alone answer with additional value and screenshots, and which _fully answers the question_, which is: "how to use Conditional formatting to make cells with formulas bold, and cells with user-typed data normal".

Comment: @BlindSpots, I think your downvote is out-of-place.

Comment: I'm not downvoting your answer but I won't upvote it unless it adds something more substantial.